# Xamarin.Forms android Entry inside TableView not working properly

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Simple Entry inside tableView.

When pressing the first time on the entry, the keyboard appears but the focus dissappears. 
clicking on the keyboard does nothing. 
Only when pressing again on the entry the keyboard is writing letters inside the Entry

EntryCell is not good enough for me and it also didn't work when i replaced the Entry with EntryCell

```
        TableView tableView = new TableView();
        tableView.Intent = TableIntent.Form;
        tableView.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
        tableView.HasUnevenRows = true;
        tableView.Root = new TableRoot()
        {
            new TableSection()
            {
                new ViewCell() { View = new Entry() { WidthRequest = 100, BackgroundColor = Color.Red} }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Actually you should replace the `ViewCell` (not the Entry) by the `EntryCell` if it's the case. Otherwise, it seems the entry is loosing focus. Have you omited some event asign, behavior or trigger on the sample code?

Comment: I Also tried EntryCell and it has the same problem